# Class "CRM_Core_DAO" not found

Tags: autoloading

I have CiviCRM 5.56.1 installed via composer on a Drupal 9 application. In a custom module I use API v4 to manipulate records. For example, get membership types.

```
\Civi\Api4\MembershipType::get()->addWhere('name', 'My Membership')->execute();
```

The error that I get is the following:

```
Error: Class "CRM_Core_DAO" not found in /var/www/html/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Utils/CoreUtil.php on line 101 #0 /var/www/html/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/DAOGetAction.php(156): Civi\Api4\Utils\CoreUtil::getOperators()
```

In my civicrm settings file I have made sure to add the correct `$civicrm_root` variable. I have check the resulting include paths and the correct civicrm core path is included. CiviCRM in general works fine via the UI. The same command works when using the `cv` CLI.

Any ideas why this happens when calling from within Drupal? It seems namespaced classes are found. In older related questions it is suggesting to use `civicrm_initialize()`, but this function does not seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is invoking the service and initializing it from there. That will give you access to API4.

```
$civicrm = \Drupal::service('civicrm');
$civicrm->initialize();
```

Alternatively -
`\Drupal::service('civicrm')->initialize();`

Additionally, you can use the following to access API related classes:

```
use Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm;
use Civi\Api4\Contact;
use Civi\Api4\Membership;
use Civi\Api4\Address;
use Civi\Api4\Phone;
use Civi\Api4\Email;

//in function
$memberships = Membership::get(FALSE)
  ->addSelect...........
$contacts = Contact::get(FALSE)
  ->addSelect.........

//etc
```

Comment: `\Drupal::service('civicrm')->initialize();` did the trick, thanks.